# Magento: Delete product images & product data

Tags: magento

The following code deleting product data & images from magento store by entit_id.

```
$product_id = 22894; //use your own product id
$mediaApi = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api");

try {
    $items = $mediaApi->items($product_id);
    foreach($items as $item) {
    $mediaApi->remove($product_id, $item['file']);
    Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load( $product_id  )->delete();
    echo $product_id." >>> "." Product deleted Successfully";
    }
} catch (Exception $exception){
    var_dump($exception);
    die('Exception Thrown');
}
```

This script deleting all product data and images, but image file is not delete from folder. How can I delete file from storage folder.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

If `$item['file']` is path to file on filesystem you can try to use

```
unlink($item['file']);
```

after deleting product data.